# How to set a default preferred size (redefining UI) in a *ComponentUI class (Swing app)?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jbutton, look-and-feel

I extended the system look and feel to draw custom `JButton`.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
UIManager.put("ButtonUI", "com.my.package.MyButtonUI");
```

With `com.my.package.MyButtonUI`:

```
public class MyButtonUI extends BasicButtonUI {

    public static final int BTN_HEIGHT = 24;
    private static final MyButtonUI INSTANCE = new MyButtonUI ();

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent b) {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        AbstractButton b = (AbstractButton) c;
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        GradientPaint gp;
        if (b.isEnabled()) {
            gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.red, 0, BTN_HEIGHT * 0.6f, Color.gray, true);
        } else {
            gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.black, 0, BTN_HEIGHT * 0.6f, Color.blue, true);
        }
        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, b.getWidth(), BTN_HEIGHT);
        super.paint(g, b);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        AbstractButton b = (AbstractButton) c;
        b.setForeground(Color.white);
        paint(g, b);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to add that constraint on these buttons: I want the buttons to have size of 70x24 except if a `setPreferredSize()` has been called in the client code. How can I do that?

Note: If I put a `setPreferredSize()` in the `MyButtonUI.update()` method, it overrides the client `setPreferredSize()`, then all my buttons get the same size.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Guillaume, I overrided `getPreferredSize()` (in `MyButtonUI`) like this:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
    AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) c;
    int width = Math.max(button.getWidth(), BUTTON_WIDTH);
    int height = Math.max(button.getHeight(), BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply override the method `getPreferredSize()` in your class `MyButtonUI`. If a programmer voluntarily sets the preferred size to something else, your code will not be called. That is the default behaviour of JComponent.

See the code of `getPreferredSize()`:

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }
    Dimension size = null;
    if (ui != null) {
        size = ui.getPreferredSize(this);
    }
    return (size != null) ? size : super.getPreferredSize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the preferred size to 70x24 in the button's constructor, setting that preference. If a client calls setPreferredSize again, it will override that.

Comment: Because it does not work with the buttons of dialogs from `JOptionPane.showXxxDialog(...)`. Thank you.

Comment: Also, if the user is able to switch between different L&F, going back and forward to that UI will drop the preferred size that has been set.