# Can I change a custom ComponentUI dynamically?

Tags: java, user-interface, dynamic

I specifically want to change the width of all scrollbars (JScrollBar) dynamically - is this possible? I was thinking that it would be best to write a custom ScrollbarUI, but I haven't been able to find any information on altering a ComponentUI dynamically.

edit: My approach so far is to have a static int that's referenced for the scrollbar width, which I then change. This predictably does nothing, as the scrollbars have no reason to think they need to be repainted. I want to avoid having a list of all scrollbars in my application, as this would sort of defeat the purpose of changing the ScrollbarUI; however, it may be necessary.

**In summary, I'm looking to change the width of every scrollbar in my application dynamically using ComponentUI.**

I was able to solve this problem from this answer: [How to set a default preferred size (redefining UI) in a *ComponentUI class (Swing app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642369/how-to-set-a-default-preferred-size-redefining-ui-in-a-componentui-class-swi)

Comment: First try it. Post problem if you have while doing so.

Comment: I did try sorry, will edit post.

Comment: First off, don't use static, unless you want ALL the scroll bars to use the size. Understand how the UIManager properties system works, understand how the PropertyChange system works. If you ComponentUI doesn't provide any kind of notification about changes, you could try using updateUI from JComponent

Comment: I do want to change all the scroll bars.